# Post request keeps getting a 404 code

Tags: angular

I worked through Angular's Tour of Heroes tutorial project and want to modify that code for my own purposes. I made a minor change to one of the service methods (in hero.service.ts to put a name on it) to call a working API endpoint.

```
create(name: string): Promise<Hero> {
    return this.http
        .post("http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value", JSON.stringify({name: name}), {headers: this.headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => res.json().data as Hero)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Calling this method is constantly giving me a 404 reponse, Firefox' console gives:

```
13:29:58.821 An error occurred Object { _body: Object, status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Object, type: null, url: "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value" } 1 hero.service.js:27:9
HeroService.prototype.handleError http://localhost:3000/app/hero.service.js:27:9
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:381:17
onInvoke http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4132:28
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:380:17
Zone.prototype.run http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:141:24
scheduleResolveOrReject/< http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:805:52
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:414:17
onInvokeTask http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4123:28
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:413:17
Zone.prototype.runTask http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:181:28
drainMicroTaskQueue http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:574:25
ZoneTask/this.invoke http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:480:25
```

I cannot even see an outgoing POST request in network traffic. What am I missing here?

Comment: 404 means it didn't find the endpoint. Do you have to give a name to the body you send ? Can't you just do `JSON.stringify(name)` ?

Comment: Tried it and worked fine for me, were you previously using in-memory-web-api by any chance? Then that will mess with your request, you need to remove that part from your ngModule in case you are using it

Comment: AJT_82, im-memory-web-api was the reason, removed it and everything works as expected.